# Weak convergence of $n \cdot 1_{[0, \frac {1} {n}]}$ in $L^1(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis

How can one show that the sequence $n \cdot 1_{[ 0, \frac {1} {n} ]}$ does not converge weakly  in $L^1(0,1)$?

Comment: One might start by stating the definition of weak convergence.

Comment: Suppose it converges weakly to $f \in L^1(0,1)$.  Then deduce contradictory properties for $f$.  For example, $\int_a^1 f$ = 0 for all $a>0$ but $\int_0^1 f = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume it does converge weakly to $f$ and fix $1>\varepsilon>0$. Consider
$$ g_\varepsilon= 1_{\{ f>0\} \cap [\varepsilon, 1)} - 1_{\{f<0\} \cap [\varepsilon, 1)} $$
Then we have $g_\varepsilon\in L^\infty\cong (L^1)'$. Test $g_\varepsilon$ on the weak sequence and conclude
$$ \Vert f \cdot 1_{[\varepsilon,1]} \Vert_1 = 0$$
Use this to conclude $f=0$. However
$$ 0= \int 1\cdot f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int 1 \cdot n 1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]} =1$$
Thus, we have a contradiction.